# How to get this inequality?

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $x$ is rational, and $x^2>3$, and $\delta=\frac{x^2-3}{2|x|}$, and $y\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ and $h=y-x$. Since $|h|<\delta$, we get $y^2=x^2+2xh+h^2>x^2-2|x|\delta=3$.

I can't figure out how we got this inequality: $x^2+2xh+h^2>x^2-2|x|\delta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^{2}+2xh+h^{2}\geq x^{2}+2xh\geq x^{2}-2|x||h|>x^{2}-2|x|\delta$.

Comment: Sorry for responding so late, but, how did you get $xh\ge -|xh|$? I know that for $a\ge0$, we have the inequality $|x|\le a$ if and only if $-a\le x\le a$.But we don't know if $xh$ is nonnegative or not.

Comment: Just take for example that $2\geq -2=-|2|$, $-2\geq -2=-|-2|$.